# How can i measure the size of a json file in javascript without use .length

Tags: javascript, json

In the application that i use on my job, we need to set a maximum pdf size that the user can insert in the application.

Comment: Try this
<input type=file id="f" onchange="alert(f.files[0].size)">

Answer (score 1):

Are you serializing the PDF and sending it in a JSON request?

If that is the case you could ask for the blob size during the serialization. However I would strongly recommend against this approach.

If you use a regular HTML form you could set the `maxSize` attribute